# spring Quartz scheduler not accessing database

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-integration, quartz-scheduler

here is my 'GenericQuartzJob' class

```
public class GenericQuartzJob extends QuartzJobBean
{

    private String batchProcessorName;

    public String getBatchProcessorName() {
        return batchProcessorName;
    }

    public void setBatchProcessorName(String name) {
//      System.out.println("jo"+name);
        this.batchProcessorName = name;
    }

    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext jobCtx) throws JobExecutionException
    {
        try {
//          System.out.println("jo");
            SchedulerContext schedCtx = jobCtx.getScheduler().getContext();

            ApplicationContext appCtx =
                (ApplicationContext) schedCtx.get("applicationContext");
            java.lang.Runnable proc = (java.lang.Runnable) appCtx.getBean(batchProcessorName);
            proc.run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
//            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new JobExecutionException("Unable to execute batch job: " + batchProcessorName, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `MyRunnableJob` Class

```
 @Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.ehydromet.service")
public class MyRunnableJob    implements Runnable {

    //@Resource private SpringService myService;
 @Autowired
 public UserService service;
    @Override
    public void run() {
//      System.out.println("hu");
        try{
        service.getAllAdminUser();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage()+" MyRunnableJob");
        }MqttImplement mqtt=new MqttImplement();
        mqtt.publishMessage();
        //Run the Job. This code will run in the Spring context so you can use injected dependencies here.
    }
}
```

Below is my `MqttImplement` class

```
public class MqttImplement implements MqttCallback {
@Autowired
private static UserService service;
@RequestMapping("/publish")
    public void publishData(ModelMap map){
        MyTask.map=map;
        pubTopic="tmsdata";
        susTopic="tmsack";
        if(initializeMqTTParameters()   ){
            if(suscribeForAck()){
//              new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-quartz.xml");    
                AbstractApplicationContext  context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
            }
        }


//      initializeMqTTParameters();
//      suscribeForAck();
//       publishMessage();

    }
    public  void publishMessage(){

        try{


//       System.out.print("sending ");
             Received received=service.getReceivedDataToPublishTMS();
         if(received!=null){
             System.out.print("sending you not null"); 
             String publisgMSG=createMessageToPublish(received);
             pubMessage="lava," ;
             publishMessageTms();
         }else{
             System.out.println("null hora");
         }
         }catch(Exception ex){
             System.out.println("hora"+ex.getLocalizedMessage()+" "+ex.toString());
         }
    }
}
```

and here is xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

<!--     <bean id="exampleBusinessObject" class="com.ehydromet"/> -->

    <!-- Old JobDetail Definition
    <bean id="jobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="exampleBusinessObject"/>
        <property name="targetMethod" value="doIt"/>
    </bean>
    -->

    <!-- Runnable Job: this will be used to call my actual job. Must implement runnable -->
    <bean name="myRunnableJob" class="com.ehydromet.controller.MyRunnableJob"></bean>

    <!-- New Clusterable Definition -->
    <bean id="jobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.ehydromet.schedule.GenericQuartzJob" />
        <property name="jobDataAsMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="batchProcessorName" value="myRunnableJob" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
        <!-- see the example of method invoking job above -->
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="jobDetail"/>
        <!-- 10 seconds -->
        <property name="startDelay" value="5000"/>
        <!-- repeat every 50 seconds -->
        <property name="repeatInterval" value="5000"/>
    </bean>
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.ehydromet.service"/>
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.ehydromet.dao"/>
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.ehydromet.service.impl"/>
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.ehydromet.dao.impl"/>
        <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
            <value>com.ehydromet.entity.Alarms</value>
                <value>com.ehydromet.entity.UserData</value>
                <value>com.ehydromet.entity.ModemInfo</value>
                <value>com.ehydromet.entity.Received</value>
                <value>com.ehydromet.entity.Modems</value>
                <value>com.ehydromet.entity.AdminLogin</value>
                <value>com.ehydromet.entity.UserPolicy</value>

            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
       <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
        </property>
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="simpleTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <!-- Add this to make the Spring Context Available -->
        <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey"><value>applicationContext</value></property>

    </bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ejava" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="hibernateInterceptor" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Dao classes are `@Transactional` and `@Repository`.

in `MqttImplement` class service object is null i think autowired is not working with Quartz scheduler. Any suggestion????
i think autowired is kind of resolved. but 
error is-- `org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'sessionFactory' of bean class [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean]: Bean property 'sessionFactory' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?`
i am new to it. so may be some foolish mistakes i have done, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `@Autowired` without `static`? Seems weird for me...

From other side you do this:

```
 MqttImplement mqttPublishTms=new MqttImplement();
 ................
 mqttPublishTms.publishMessage();
```

So, it's `new` not Dependency Injection. There is no surprise that the `service` property there is `null`.

Comment: but i also tried to call service object in class MyTask service.getAllAdminUser();

Comment: cause i also tried it with without static keyword and i used it cause i was wondering that "new" keyword will not inject the dependency so i make the publishMessage class "static" and then tried it but didn't work and i forget to remove it so.......